# Invisisble background for Spinner?

Tags: java, android, layout

I am trying hard to have a Spinner look like Textview meaning the displayed selection should have no frame or color or transparency, I would like just the displayed value text and nothing else.  I have been playing with .9.png files and gimp but haven't made headway.  is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the btn_default_normal, opened it in gimp and erased the button leaving the boundry markers and I had an invisible background!  works like a charm but the battle continues.